# searching for an unnamed nested XElement by a specific XAttribute

Tags: c#, linq, xelement, xattribute

Here is what my XML looks like (Yes, I know the XML is ugly).  I'm trying to search and remove any nodes from this XDocument that have the isConstField attribute set to "Y" without iterating through each individual XElement.

```
<Root>
    <Node>
        <SubNode>
            <SubNode2>
                <FieldNameA isConstField="Y"></FieldNameA>
                <FieldNameB></FieldNameB>
                <FieldNameC isConstField="N"></FieldNameC>
            </SubNode2>
        </SubNode>
        <SubNode>
            <SubNode2>
                <FieldNameD></FieldNameD>
                <FieldNameE></FieldNameE>
                <FieldNameF></FieldNameF>
            </SubNode2>
        </SubNode>
    </Node>
</Root>
```

Here is how I'm trying to do it

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\junk\Test\Test\Data.xml");
doc.Descendants("Root").Elements().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("isConstField") == "Y").Remove();
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

`.Elements()` will only return direct child elements.
You want `.Descendants()`, which returns all nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with XPath extensions (don't forget to add `System.Xml.XPath` namespace reference):

```
doc.XPathSelectElements("//*[@isConstField='Y']").Remove();
```

Expression matches any node which have `isConstField` attribute equal to `Y`. `XPathSelectElements` selects all such nodes. And then all selected nodes are removed.